# Get day/month from new Date(date) getting current day/month

Tags: javascript

I'm having trouble with new Date constructor,

when i set new Date(date) and ask console to print it, then it returns the date i want but if i try to get the day/month it returns my current day/month as if i was setting to `new Date().getDay()`

```
let date, end;

date = new Date()
end = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth() + 1, 0)

console.log(end) // prints: Thu Oct 31 2019 00:00:00 GMT-0300 (Horário Padrão de Brasília)
console.log(end.getDay()) // prints: 4
```

I want the output to be 31 but it's not working, am i doing something wrong?

Comment: use getDate() instead of getDay().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**if you want to print the date (1-31) , you have to use the method getDate().**

```
let date, end;

date = new Date()
end = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth() + 1, 0)

console.log(end) // prints: Thu Oct 31 2019 00:00:00 GMT-0300 (Horário Padrão de Brasília)
console.log(end.getDate()) // prints: 31
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are using the wrong method

```
let end = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth() + 1, 0)

console.log(end) // prints: Thu Oct 31 2019 00:00:00 GMT-0300 (Horário Padrão de Brasília)
console.log(end.getDay()) // Returns the day of the week
console.log(end.getDate()) // Returns the day of the month
```

Answer (score 0):

`getDay()` doesn't return the number of the day in the month. It returns the day in the week.

Use `getDate()` for your desired return. Also you can check the document in [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)